# How do I declare namespace functions correctly

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces

I thought I followed the logic of the other threads on this, but

```
namespace Geometry {

class Vector2D {
    public:
        Vector2D(float x_, float y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}
        float x;
        float y;
}

Vector2D operator+(const Vector2D &lhs, const Vector2D &rhs) {
    return Vector2D(lhs.x + rhs.x, lhs.y + rhs.y);
}

}
```

is not compiling, and I get the error

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'class Vector2D'
Vector2D operator+(const Vector2D &lhs, const Vector2D &rhs) {

error: expected ';' after top level declarator
Vector2D operator+(const Vector2D &lhs, const Vector2D &rhs) {
```

so the compiler seems to think my operator overload on binary '+' is a delcaration of a variable?

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after the closing brace of the class definition.

Comment: Consider deleting the question before the "Ah, you're missing a semicolon!" answers start pouring in.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: LOL I got an accept from it too

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet This *is* really, really funny!

Comment: @I am *so* looking forward to that [typo-hammer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319399/335858)!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Accept is gone :(

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Accept is back wtf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, you're missing a semicolon!